# How is a DynamoDB UpdateItem call charged when nothing is updated?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I execute a DynamoDB command to update an item and the item already exists and there is nothing to update, does DynamoDB count that as a write operation or a read operation?

In my scenario I need to keep track of if any request has happened in the month for a customer and if so, write a row. I don't need to keep a count. So at most I'll write a row once per month per customer but I'll need to do this check thousands or potentially millions of times per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB always charges based on the type of operation you are doing, so an update will always use WCU. You can verify this for yourself by performing an experiment in which you repeatedly update an existing item without making any changes, and then checking your consumed capacity.

If a write fails because of a ConditionExpression, the operation will incur a cost of 1 WCU. Otherwise, the operation will use the number of WCUs required to write the whole item, regardless of how many attributes are updated.